# Memory warnings/leaks

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, uiimagepickercontroller

### **EDIT 1**: This problem specially happens on iOS7.

I'm trying to crop an image that was already taken by the **UIImagePickerController** using some Core Graphics methods inside the `imagePickerController` method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)photoPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if(modeSelected == kModeTypeAutomatic){
        //cropping image
        if(image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp){
            CGImageRef tmpImgRef = [image CGImage];
            CGImageRef topImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(image.size.width/2, 0, image.size.width/2, image.size.height));
            secondImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImgRef];
            CGImageRelease(topImgRef);
        }
        else{
            CGImageRef tmpImgRef = [image CGImage];
            CGImageRef topImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height/2.0));
            secondImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImgRef scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
            CGImageRelease(topImgRef);

        }
    }

    image = nil;

    [photoPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    if (secondImage) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondPicTakenSegue" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

I made some allocations and memory leaks using Instrument, and I verified that the problem is inside this method.
Am I not releasing something here? Is something missing?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using the static analyzer? `CMD+Shift+B`

Comment: What type of object does Instruments say is leaking? It looks like you're not releasing `secondImage` in this method, but I'm guessing you use it elsewhere.

Comment: @user1118321 Yes, indeed I'm using ARC on it.

Comment: @Sean I tried, but nothing is shown

Comment: Instruments should tell you what type of object each leak is. In the bottom half of the window, for every entry in the table, it should say its size and what class it's from. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

This may be your issue (from the `CGImage` reference, under `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`):

> The resulting image retains a reference to the original image, which means you may release the original image after calling this function.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_6

So you may want to try a `CGImageRelease(tmpImgRef)` since it sounds like you may be incrementing the reference count with that call to `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`.  I haven't tested this myself to ensure that this is the case, but perhaps worth a shot.

Comment: Perhaps the other answer is onto something. Does `secondImage` have any value prior to the newly created `UIImage` being assigned?  Is it possible that elsewhere in your code, something has retained the old value's `CGImage`?

Comment: Hi Manny! No, `secondImage`is assigned inside that method I shared.

Comment: Is its value `nil` when you come into this method? You're performing a check on `secondImage.imageOrientation` so it seems you expect it to have some value. In addition to confirming what I originally wrote in this answer,  I would also check to see what `secondImage` is set to when this method is hit. If it's coming in with some value, I would then go back and make sure there isn't an instance where it's `CGImage` should be released elsewhere (in other words, if anything aside from the wrapping `UIImage` is retaining it).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from that code snippet, but `secondImage` could be what's being leaked. No harm in explicitly setting it to `nil` in your `dealloc` method to see if that helps:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    secondImage = nil;
}
```

Comment: He doesn't state how he's defining `secondImage`, but he's using ARC so `dealloc` is generally not needed for a `UIImage`.  He also explicitly releases the `CGImageRef` created for `secondImage`, so I would be surprised if that's it.